# Indexing doc/pdf/docx file into solr using ContentStreamUpdateRequest

Tags: solrj, solr4, java-6

Hi I am here using Solr 4.7.2 for indexing the document.

Using ContentStreamUpdateRequest of solrj I am trying to index a file in Solr but while 
I am sending a file path and unique id field as an input using UI

In action class while sending the object of ContentStreamUpdateRequest passing parameter to solrServer object
i.e

```
SolrServer solrServer = ..;
solrServer.request(contentStreamUpdateRequest);
```

I am getting following error

```
Exception:
    org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException

Exception message:
    error reading streams
```

Exception trace:

```
at   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:382)
at   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:199)
at   com.adastra.candidate.search.solr.action.SolrUpdateAction.aaaExecute(SolrUpdateAction.java:49)
at   com.adastra.base.action.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:181)
at   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
at   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
at   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
at   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
at   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
at   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
at   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can please suggest me in fixing it.

Comment: Can you post the complete error message ? Looks like you are giving the wrong encoding or the path is incorrect ?

Comment: Are you talking about file path

Comment: Post complete stack trace. There must be more

Comment: It is complete stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I think that in version 4.7.2 streaming is disabled by default and you have to enable it in file solrconfig.xml

change

```
<requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="false"
```

to

```
<requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true"
```

Also, have a look at the documentation
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity#Streaming_Consideration

Let me know if this fixed the issue. Be aware of security when enabling remote streaming.